# Rails ActiveRecord Create or Find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 App and in my post method for an api i want to find the record based on what the user is trying to create and if it doesn't exist create it and if it does update the parameters that it has. I wrote some code that actually does this but it takes a bit to execute. Is there any other way of doing the same exact thing with possibly less code or queries.

```
@picture = current_picture.posts.where(post_id: params[:id]).first_or_initialize
@picture.update_attributes(active: true, badge: parameters[:badge], identifier: parameters[:identifier])
render json: @picture
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Rails 4.0 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) denote that `find_by_` **has not** been deprecated:

> All dynamic methods *except* for find_by_... and find_by_...! are
>   deprecated.

Additionally, according to the [Rails 4.0 documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by), the `find_or_create_by` method *is still* available, but has been rewritten to conform to the following syntax:

```
@picture = current_picture.posts.find_or_create_by(post_id: params[:id])
```

**UPDATE:**

According to the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/24c4195bab27ed9d76d0e126044e7f932de9e30e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb):

```
# rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb
def find_or_create_by(attributes, &block)
  find_by(attributes) || create(attributes, &block)
end
```

Thus, it stands to reason that multiple attributes can be passed as arguments to `find_or_create_by` in Rails 4.

Comment: Thank you but i thought that method was depreciated in Rails 4, i guess not. So i'm also using 'current_picture.posts.where(active: true, post_id: params[:id]).take!' elsewhere, should that be written differently?

Comment: I've updated my answer. According to the documentation, you can find a user's first post with the `post_id` equal to `params[:id]`, or otherwise create new user's post with the `active` attribute set to `true`: `current_picture.posts.create_with(active: true).find_or_create_by(post_id: params[:post_id])`.

Comment: Thanks what if the post exists, will it set the existing post to true?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a citation to the source code that indicates that multiple attributes _can indeed_ be passed to find_or_create_by.

Comment: Yes but if it finds the record will it update the record with the parameters?

Comment: Dynamic finders are being deprecated in Rails 4, e.g. `User.find_by_email('user@example.com')` and instead you'll have to write `User.where( email: 'user@example.com')`. [See the changes for ActiveRecord in Rails4 here](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013)

Comment: @ny95, have you tried it? If you pass two parameters, and a record is found matching both, then the existing record is returned (and you can thus operate on it). Otherwise, a new record will be created matching both attributes.

Comment: @Carl, the __official__ Rails 4.0 release notes (which I've cited in my answer) denote that `All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated.` – emphasis on ___except___.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows,

@picture = current_picture.posts.where(post_id: params[:id]).find_or_create.

This will find post with params[:id] and if it doesn't find that record then it will create record post under current picture with this id.