# Rails 4.1.1 ActiveAdmin undefined method find_or_create_by_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I swear I tried absolutely everything to avoid posting this question. I've been working on this problem literally all day.

Whenever I try to delete more than one user or edit a single user I get the following error:

```
A NoMethodError occurred in users#update:

  undefined method `find_or_create_by_id' for #<Class:0x00000006fed200>
  app/admin/users.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Basically I have a customized users.rb file that reads as follows:

app/admin/users.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  config.batch_actions = true
  index do
    selectable_column
    actions defaults: true
    column :id
    column :name
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :current_sign_in_ip
    column :country
  end


  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :superadmin, :label => "Super Administrator"
      f.input :ip_address
    end
    f.actions "User Details2" do
      f.action :submit, :as => :button
      f.action :cancel, :as => :link
    end
  end

  create_or_edit = Proc.new {
    @user            = User.find_or_create_by_id(params[:id])
    @user.superadmin = params[:user][:superadmin]
    @user.attributes = params[:user].delete_if do |k, v|
      (k == "superadmin") ||
      (["password", "password_confirmation"].include?(k) && v.empty? && !@user.$
    end
    if @user.save
      redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user.id
    else
      render active_admin_template((@user.new_record? ? 'new' : 'edit') + '.htm$
    end
  }
  member_action :create, :method => :post, &create_or_edit
  member_action :update, :method => :put, &create_or_edit

end
```

I've tried everything I could think of... looked at all the similar threads... and I've come up with absolutely nothing. So does anyone out there have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
User.where(id: params[:id]).first_or_create
```

Those finders are deprecated since 4 and removed since 4.1
http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: I'm sure both of your methods would work but I like yours better for being slightly less cumbersome. I don't think find_or_create_by is deprecated... but it should be. And probably will be eventually ("where" is just so much easier to use...) Thanks much.

Comment: It was actually removed, because of beeing much cleaner and because it does not have to use meta_programming. This is what the message is saying `undefined method find_or_create_by_id`. This method no longer exists. U can put them back, if your app would be havylly relying on them, by requiring the gem: `activerecord-deprecated_finders`

Comment: In that case I chose wisely!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `User.find_or_create_by(user_id: params[:id])`per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905038/rails-activerecord-create-or-find) and the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/24c4195bab27ed9d76d0e126044e7f932de9e30e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb).

NOTE: They have not been deprecated as functions. They have merely changed form to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations).

Comment: Well now I have the problem of who to give the green checkmark to since you both answered at the same time...

Comment: Just so you know. They are still in rails. The source code for 4.1 stable has them [as you can see here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb) (ctrl-f `find_or_create_by` to see the usage) I don't know why user1035375 is insisting they aren't. He cited some blog that only said the old form was deprecated which is true. You weren't using the old form though. I tested this on rails 4.1.1 *without* the `activerecord-deprecated_finders` gem and it still works.

Comment: In that case I'm glad I upvoted you! :) The new version is still cleaner,  though